# How to fetch partial data from an active coonection?

Tags: php, curl, fsockopen

I making a script which save some no. ( any type of unique 9 digit no. ) from fetching a page .

The page which i have to fetch data is a remote file downloader . first we send a url to download in scond paage it provide a after some basic html and style code after it provide a line `<script>luid = 999999999;</script>` and then it continuously buffers the download status . so its take a long time to fetch the page and get the 9 digit unique no. i saw in firefox it delivers earlier . so i am thinking is there is any solution to fetch it without wait to load the whole page .

i can use any thing supported by php . like fsockeopen , curl .. anyting..

thanks

Comment: You have the right idea. Simply open the connection, start reading X bytes until you arrive at your desired position, then close the connection. One thing to keep in mind is when you are reading bytes in buffer, you may end up with a partial of the content you are expecting, i.e., <script>12323  and the next buffer would contain the rest </script>

Comment: @JohnCartwright well i got your posint . but how to do it in fsockopen or curl i mean anything to add or edit there ? or something .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server and URL support ranges, you can set PHP/CURL's CURLOPT_RANGE option to request that the server only return only the first X bytes of the page. The server is free to ignore that, though, so if that doesn't work you can use John Cartwright's suggestion and just abort the download once you've received the data you want. Using PHP/CURL, you'd set a write callback function with CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, and monitor the download from that function as it happens. Once you've received the data you want, just return 0 from the function and the download will be aborted.